# Generic method on complex and different data structures

Tags: java, templates, generics

I want to create a generic method for complex structure, but I can't figure out how to match the method's signature to my data structures.

I've the following structure:

A class I am using:

```
public class Individual <T extends AnInterface> {

    final List<T> data;

    public Individual(final List<T> data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    public List<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

A smaller structure I am using:

```
public class Tuple3<T1,T2,T3> {

    public T1 _1;
    public T2 _2;
    public T3 _3;

    public Tuple3(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3){
        _1 = t1;
        _2 = t2;
        _3 = t3;
    }

}
```

A generic class in which I want to use a generic method:

```
class MyTemplatedClass <..., T2 extends AnInterface, ...> 
    implements ... {

    private Map<Integer,        List<Tuple3<Integer, Individual<T2>, Double>>> resultsByIteration;
    private Map<Individual<T2>, List<Tuple3<Integer, Individual<T2>, Double>>> resultsByIndividual;
    private int iteration = 0;

    @Override
    public <T2 extends AnInterface> void evaluatePopulationAndStoreResults(List<Individual<T2>> elements) {

        // changing iteration
        // calculating fitness
        for (Individual<T2> element : elements) {

            Tuple3<Integer, Individual<T2>, Double> triplet = new Tuple3<>(iteration, element, fitness);

            /// I want this operation to be templated for both strutures
            doSomeListOperationOnMapForAGivenKey(resultsByIteration,  new Integer(5), triplet);
            doSomeListOperationOnMapForAGivenKey(resultsByIndividual, elements, triplet);
        }
    }

    /// How should doSomeListOperationOnMapForAGivenKey() method's signature look like, if I want to call this on both data structures???
    // this signature does not match to the above calls :(
    public <KEY_TYPE, VALUE_TYPE> void doSomeListOperationOnMapForAGivenKey(Map<KEY_TYPE, List<VALUE_TYPE>> map, KEY_TYPE key, VALUE_TYPE value){
        // some list operation:
        // check if key is in map
          // if not, then create a list, add the value to the list and put the key and value into the map
          // if yes, then check if is there any similar tuple in the list under the key
            // it there is no similar tuple, then add the value to the list
            // if there is a similar tuple, then update with the value
    }

}
```

I am getting a compile error to this signature:

```
 public <KEY_TYPE, VALUE_TYPE> void doSomeListOperationOnMapForAGivenKey(Map<KEY_TYPE, List<VALUE_TYPE>> map, KEY_TYPE key, VALUE_TYPE value)
```

I cant figure out how should `doSomeListOperationOnMapForAGivenKey()` method's signature look like, if I want to do the same map and list operations on both structures with different types. I want this method to be as generic as possible. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Thank to Radiodef's comment a mistake was repaired in the definition of the class, what now looks like this:

```
class MyTemplatedClass <..., T2 extends AnInterface, ...> 
    implements SomeOtherInterface<T2> {...}
```

and the caller method's signature is the following:

```
@Override
public void evaluatePopulationAndStoreResults(List<Individual<T2>> elements) {...}
```

Comment: These types have nothing in common.  So it seems this method should just have generic param `<K, V>`.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: `public <K, V> void doSomeListOperationOnMapForAGivenKey(Map<K, List<V>> map, K key, V value)`.

Comment: To put it another way - because these types are unrelated, your method can't really do anything useful without significant reflection.  It seems that you should really have two separate overloads.

Comment: I think the pattern above I tried is the same what you wrote, but it does not matches. The types may be unrelated, but I want to do only Map and List related operations and this operation should be the same for both types.

Comment: This might just be a side-note, but the `<T2 extends AnInterface>` in the declaration of `evaluatePopulationAndStoreResults` seems like a mistake. That type variable `T2` shadows the `T2` declared on the class, sort of like when you declare a local variable which has the same name as an instance member.

Comment: @user1802693 - Can you clarify (in code) **what** you want the content of that method to do?

Comment: Actually, I guess my previous comment is not a side-note, because that appears to be the source of a compiler error which you didn't mention.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth  I've clarified the operation I want to implement there.

Comment: @Radiodef You are right, I forget to mention it. (I've updated the post.) But I still want to match the method's T2 type to the individual's and class's T2 type..

Comment: @Radiodef You were right! To match those types the interface needs a type parameter. The original problem is still unsolved but thanks for the side-note! (I will update the post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the compiler error is trying to tell you is that the `T2` declared on the class and the `T2` declared on the method `evaluatePopulationAndStoreResults` refer to different types.

```
class MyTemplatedClass <..., T2 extends AnInterface, ...> 
    implements ... {

    @Override
    // Declares a new type variable T2, unrelated to the
    // T2 declared on the class and shadows it.
    //     vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    public <T2 extends AnInterface> void evaluatePopulationAndStoreResults(...) {
        {

            Tuple3<Integer, Individual<T2>, Double> triplet =
                new Tuple3<>(iteration, element, fitness);

            doSomeListOperationOnMapForAGivenKey(resultsByIteration,
                                                 new Integer(5),
                                                 triplet);
        }
    }
```

What is actually happening is like this:

```
// One type variable declared on the class, used by
// both maps.
//                           vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MyTemplatedClass <..., T2A extends AnInterface, ...> 
    implements ... {

    @Override
    // Another different type variable declared
    // on the method.
    //     vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    public <T2B extends AnInterface> void evaluatePopulationAndStoreResults(...) {
        {

            Tuple3<Integer, Individual<T2B>, Double> triplet =
                new Tuple3<>(iteration, element, fitness);

            //                              Passing a Map using T2A
            //                                   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            doSomeListOperationOnMapForAGivenKey(resultsByIteration,
                                                 new Integer(5),
            //           Passing a Tuple3<..., T2B, ...>
            //                                   vvvvvvv
                                                 triplet);
        }
    }
```

But in your code, both type variables have the same name. This is similar to what happens when declaring a local variable with the same name as an instance member.

As far as I can tell, you can just remove the type variable declaration on `evaluatePopulationAndStoreResults`. When you declared a type variable on a class, the entire class has access to it.

I think that the snippet as-shown ought to compile if you remove the shadowing type variable declaration.

Comment: You were right! The T2 in my method was really shadowed. I've changed an other interface I implement, and removed the generic from the overriden method and this solved my problem..
Thank you for your help!